# How to upload object with ng2-file-upload FileItem in field?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript

I want to upload file inside object using `HttpClient`.

```
export class Building {
  name: string;
  picture?: FileItem;
}

private onAfterAddingFile(fileItem: FileItem) {
  console.log(fileItem);
  this.form.get('picture').setValue(fileItem);
  this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/en/buildings/', this.form.value)
   .subscribe(res => { console.log(res) });
```

}

**How can I send post with file loaded to class field with [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload)?**

Comment: Is it this library? https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload There's like a half dozen things called "ng2-file-upload(er)" or similar.

Comment: Added link. Yes, it is from https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload